# Django-allauth - How to enable to use same email address for difference account

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to enable user to login with username / password.
I also want to allow user to enter email address for email verification use.

Here is my settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

However, when I try to register. There will be an error message.

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'test@test.com' for key 'email'")
```

And I found that, there is a new entry in "auth_user" table.
But it can't write to "account_emailaddress" table.

Also, I found that there is a configure in mysql for "account_emailaddress"

```
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
```

How can I disable the unique email setting?

I'm using python 3.4, django 2.0, django-allauth 0.35

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell allauth in your settings.py-
 'ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email" '

This should enable the verification and use of emails as login.